# in c# How do I validate a textbox when someone types in a decimal , and I want a error shown saying no decimal numbers?

Tags: c#, .net

Every time someone types in a decimal or any characters or strings, I want a message box shown saying “only integers”.

Comment: Do you want to determine this as the user is typing or do you have some kind of button in your using that confirms the value inputted in your textbox? Or possibly detect the type of content once the user finishes to type in your textbox ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question a bit more?

Comment: What is “a textbox”? WinForm? WPF? ASP.NET? UWP?

Comment: You are that much more likely to get better help if you show what you have or tried. 
Also, be specific about the type of project Web, desktop, etc.

Comment: Show us a little bit of your code...

Answer (score 0):

In .net as your tag says: Try pasting this in some event of the Textbox, for example the Lostfocus. Remember to add the Namespace part:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions 'At the top of the form class

 Public Class FormName

 Private Sub Tbx_EscuelaElegida_LostFocus(.....

 'DECLARE VARIABLE AND ASSIGN THE TEXTBOX CONTENT TO IT
    Dim TestsVariable As String = TextboxName.text


    'IF IT DOES NOT CONTAIN INTEGERS, SHOW A MESSAGE
    If Not Regex.IsMatch(TestsVariable, "^[0-9 ]+$") Then

        MsgBox("No Decimal Numbers")

    End If

 End sub
End Class
```

Comment: I believe this is VB.net? OP requests C#.

Comment: I know, Dani. I just answered that because if you look at his tags he included ".net"  . So I thought he might know how to write some code in ".net", too and then adapt it to C#  :D